# Lettuce 6.0.1.RELEASE deprecated .withPassword

Tags: scala, redis, lettuce

With Earlier version 5.1.6.RELEASE , withPassword works perfectly.
How ever with latest version it shows warning that withPassword is deprecated.It takes Array[Char] or charSequence .

```html
  @transient lazy val redisClient = RedisClient.create(
    RedisURI.builder()
      .withHost(redisHost)
      .withPort(redisPort)
      .withPassword(redisAuth)
      .withSsl(true)
      .build()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation you shouldn't use the `withPassword` method taking a String as a parameter but use a `CharSequence` or an `Array[Char]`

> - @deprecated since 6.0. Use {@link #withPassword(CharSequence)} or {@link #withPassword(char[])} avoid String caching.

See also the [api docs](https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/RedisURI.Builder.html) or the plain comments at the [source code](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/blob/main/src/main/java/io/lettuce/core/RedisURI.java#L1465).

So if simply change your code to

```
@transient lazy val redisClient = RedisClient.create(
    RedisURI.builder()
      .withHost(redisHost)
      .withPort(redisPort)
      .withPassword(redisAuth.toCharArray)
      .withSsl(true)
      .build()
```

you will at least avoid the warning (but kind of workaround the reason why the introduced that deprecatation). Maybe this question + answers is worth reading: [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords).

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong. Is it just the deprecated warning or is it that you can't connect to Redis at all?

Comment: This is Deprecated Warning . Still able to connect.